# Adding Bars in background of Bargraph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have been having some issues with adding recession bars in the background of my graph. What is the proper way to do it?
I have tried to define geom_rect(.....) for the background but this did not work out properly.

Here is the code how i get my data:

```
library(quantmod)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)


getSymbols("USPRIV",src="FRED")
getSymbols("USGOVT",src="FRED")

#convert data from quantmod into dataframes
uspriv.df <- data.frame(date= index(USPRIV),USPRIV$USPRIV)
usgovt.df <- data.frame(date= index(USGOVT),USGOVT$USGOVT)

#calculate month-to-month difference
d.uspriv <- dplyr::mutate(uspriv.df[-1,], duspriv = uspriv.df$USPRIV[-1]-uspriv.df$USPRIV[-nrow(uspriv.df)])
d.usgovt <- dplyr::mutate(usgovt.df[-1,], dusgovt = usgovt.df$USGOVT[-1]-usgovt.df$USGOVT[-nrow(usgovt.df)])

df <- dplyr::left_join(d.uspriv, d.usgovt, by = "date")

#shorten dataframe, starting in 2007
df.2007 <- dplyr::filter(df, date >= "2007-01-01") 
df1.2007 <- dplyr::select(df.2007, date, duspriv, dusgovt)

df1 <- melt(df1.2007, id="date")

ggplot(df1, aes(x=date, y=value)) + 
        geom_bar(aes(fill=variable), 
                     stat="identity",
                 position=position_dodge()) +
        scale_fill_brewer(palette="Dark2")
```

This generates this graph [here](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-w2XMZktVKsY/VWsQU0WUQoI/AAAAAAAACJI/IfgtqitZ5a0/s640/Screen%2BShot%2B2015-05-31%2Bat%2B9.36.00%2BAM.png):

What is the most efficient way to include recession bars?
Here would be the code to obtain the data

```
getSymbols("USREC",src="FRED")

usrec.df <- data.frame(date= index(USREC), USREC$USREC)
```

If I would include the recession data into the dataframe and then melt it, how would I define the ggplot part?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but what is a "Regression Bar" exactly?

Comment: A bar indicating if the economy was in a recession. The data indicates  with a value of 1 as a recession and 0 as not. Sorry for the confusion. Example here: https://research.stlouisfed.org/fred2/series/GDP

Comment: Ah, ok. Thanks. Yeah, that can be done but I have to research it a bit. Others might know it faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a more robust solution. It should not fail when there are multiple recessions (the irony of that sentence...). Thanks to user `bergant`. 
Note: you still need to ensure there is matching USREC data for the time frame you're considering.
I've done an example starting in *1965*.

```
library(quantmod)
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)


getSymbols("USPRIV",src="FRED")
getSymbols("USGOVT",src="FRED")

#convert data from quantmod into dataframes
uspriv.df = data.frame(date= index(USPRIV),USPRIV$USPRIV)
usgovt.df = data.frame(date= index(USGOVT),USGOVT$USGOVT)

#calculate month-to-month difference
d.uspriv = dplyr::mutate(uspriv.df[-1,], duspriv = uspriv.df$USPRIV[-1]-uspriv.df$USPRIV[-nrow(uspriv.df)])
d.usgovt = dplyr::mutate(usgovt.df[-1,], dusgovt = usgovt.df$USGOVT[-1]-usgovt.df$USGOVT[-nrow(usgovt.df)])

df = dplyr::left_join(d.uspriv, d.usgovt, by = "date")

#shorten dataframe, starting in 1965
df.1965 = dplyr::filter(df, date >= "1965-01-01") 
df1.1965 = dplyr::select(df.1965, date, duspriv, dusgovt)

df1 = melt(df1.1965, id="date")


#########
getSymbols("USREC",src="FRED")
usrec = data.frame(date= index(USREC), USREC$USREC)
rownames(usrec) = NULL

new_df = merge(df1, usrec)

##############

# Thanks go out to @bergant for this bit:
dif = diff(new_df$USREC)
new_df$Status = factor(c(0, dif) - 2 * c(dif, 0), levels = -3:3)
levels(new_df$Status) = c(rep(0, 4), "Start", "End", "Start&End")

##############

start_end_dt = data.frame(
            xmin = as.Date(new_df$date[new_df$Status == "Start"])
          , xmax = as.Date(new_df$date[new_df$Status == "End"])
)

##############
```

And the rest is easy:

```
ggplot(new_df, aes(x=date, y=value)) + 
  geom_rect(    inherit.aes = FALSE
              , data = start_end_dt
              , aes(xmin = xmin
                  , xmax = xmax
                  , ymin=-Inf
                  , ymax=+Inf)
              , fill='gray'
              , alpha=0.5) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill=variable), 
           stat="identity",
           position=position_dodge()) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Dark2") +   
  theme_bw() + 
  theme( panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank() )
```

[image]

Comment: Great. Thank you very much. It works very well for this example. Do you know how to approach it if there would be two time periods with a recession?

Comment: Oddly enough, I encounter a very similar problem here as I did for data of my own I have to analyze by weeks end. Go figure (pun intended). At any rate @bergant provided a great solution. There are others at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30560843/how-to-detect-and-mark-change-within-a-column-in-another-column

Comment: I came across this one here... https://jeffreybreen.wordpress.com/2011/08/15/recession-bars/  it works for time series, not so much for bar graphs. Would this approach with start and end work for bar graphs?

Comment: One more follow up question. I tried setting the date for 1990-01-01 and it generates the 'Start' and 'End' accordingly, but somehow ggplot does not work.  This is the error: `Error in data.frame(xmin = c(7517, 11413, 13879), xmax = c(7729, 11627,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 3, 1, 592`

Comment: OK. I've fixed that. (created a start_end_dt). Hope this helps.

Comment: No problem. If you're not already familiar with it, R Cookbook [Graphs] (cookbook-r.com/Graphs) has great information on getting ggplot2 to do what you want. Cheers.